# Initialize a string in C to empty string

Tags: c, string

I want to initialize string in C to empty string.
I tried:

```
string[0] = "";
```

but it wrote

```
"warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"
```

How should I do it then?

Comment: What's the point of declaring a 0-character string?

Comment: What is the type of your `string` ? Is it a char pointer or a char array ?

Comment: @cdhowie: It can be a useful sentinel value, for instance.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood.  "string" was a variable defined previously.  I thought this was some sort of weird fubared variable declaration.

Comment: valid Question @leppie What is String.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming your array called 'string' already exists, try

```
string[0] = '\0';
```

`\0` is the explicit NUL terminator, required to mark the end of string.

Comment: @badgerr: would you please change your answer to use `'\0'` ?

Answer (score 43):

In addition to Will Dean's version, the following are common for whole buffer initialization:

```
char s[10] = {'\0'};
```

or

```
char s[10];
memset(s, '\0', sizeof(s));
```

or

```
char s[10];
strncpy(s, "", sizeof(s));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot 8 years old answer. Couldn't find much on whole buffer initialization.

Answer (score 34):

You want to set the first character of the string to zero, like this:

```
char myString[10];
myString[0] = '\0';
```

(Or `myString[0] = 0;`)

Or, actually, on initialisation, you can do:

```
char myString[10] = "";
```

But that's not a general way to set a string to zero length once it's been defined.

Comment: `char myString[1] = "";` surely?  You need space for the null terminator.

Comment: Correction: you could do `char myString[10] = "";`

Comment: @JeremyP: `""` stands for `"\0"`, so I think `char myString[1]` is enough.

Comment: @NanXiao The code said `char myString[0] = "";` when I wrote the comment. It has since been corrected.

Answer (score 5):

Assigning string literals to char array is allowed only during declaration:

```
char string[] = "";
```

This declares string as a char array of size 1 and initializes it with `\0`.

Try this too:

```
char str1[] = ""; 
char str2[5] = ""; 
printf("%d, %d\n", sizeof(str1), sizeof(str2)); //prints 1, 5
```

Answer (score 4):

`calloc` allocates the requested memory and returns a pointer to it. It also sets allocated memory to zero.

In case you are planning to use your `string` as empty string all the time:

```
char *string = NULL;
string = (char*)calloc(1, sizeof(char));
```

In case you are planning to store some value in your `string` later:

```
char *string = NULL;
int numberOfChars = 50; // you can use as many as you need
string = (char*)calloc(numberOfChars + 1, sizeof(char));
```

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this you can use:

```
strcpy(string, "");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string[0] = "";
```

```
"warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

Ok, let's dive into the expression ...

`0` an int: represents the number of chars (assuming `string` is (or decayed into) a char*) to advance from the beginning of the object `string`

`string[0]`: the `char` object located at the beginning of the object `string`

`""`: string literal: an object of type `char[1]`

`=`: assignment operator: tries to assign a value of type `char[1]` to an object of type `char`. `char[1]` (decayed to `char*`) and `char` are not assignment compatible, but the compiler trusts you (the programmer) and goes ahead with the assignment anyway by casting the type `char*` (what `char[1]` decayed to) to an `int` --- and you get the warning as a bonus. **You have a really nice compiler** :-)

Comment: Would get more upvotes if it had a solution; this is a good explanation of what's happening though.

Comment: I agree @wizzwizz4, but I like my answer as it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think Amarghosh answered correctly. If you want to Initialize an empty string(without knowing the size) the best way is:

```
//this will create an empty string without no memory allocation. 
char str[]="";// it is look like {0}
```

But if you want initialize a string with a fixed memory allocation you can do:

```
// this is better if you know your string size.    
char str[5]=""; // it is look like {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but I think your issue may be that you've created a zero-length array, rather than an array of length 1.

A string is a series of characters followed by a string terminator (`'\0'`). An empty string (`""`) consists of no characters followed by a single string terminator character - i.e. one character in total.

So I would try the following:

`string[1] = ""`

Note that this behaviour is not the emulated by `strlen`, which does not count the terminator as part of the string length.